# In Google Data Studio, is there a way to filter my data without it being fetched after each filter request?

Tags: javascript, api, rest, google-apps-script, looker-studio

[Picture for context](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7Gv6.png)

My Community Connector fetches these 2 fields (Subscription Date and Clicks).

I want to be able to filter by date so my table only shows, for example, data from the last 7 days. This works using the Date Filter that Data Studio provides, however, I notice that this date filter does another fetch request with the correct date I selected.

I don't want this to happen. I want to filter by date USING MY EXISTING DATA. Is there any way to do this? To filter only using my cached data, and not send a new GET request?

Answer (score 1):

While this is not doable from Data Studio side, you can implement your own [cache in Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/cache). You can evaluate each `getData` request and return data from the cache if needed. This will avoid sending new GET requests to your API endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

While this may not be the best option to everyone, I found a quick temp solution by loading my own community connector USING google's community connector, Extract Data. 
This way my data loads only 1 time, and I can filter it instantly the way I want.

If you want to refresh the data, you 'edit' the data source and save.